# Google OAuth2client - invalid_grant: Token has been revoked

Tags: python, pycharm, google-api-client, google-oauth, oauth2client

I'm writing a basic app that prints out projects in Google's Cloud Resources Manager using this method:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list

Yesterday it worked but I revoked the token and the code doesn't prompt to re-authorize.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

projects = service.projects() request = projects.list() while request is not None:

    response = request.execute()

    for project in response['projects']:
        print project
    request = projects.list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

> File "oauth2client/client.py", line 834, in _do_refresh_request
>       raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status) oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Token
>   has been revoked.

I think there's a way to tell the client to check if the token is valid and pop the user out to a browser if not, but can't seem to get the code to do it.  Any help appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since this code uses application default credentials, the gcloud command is how I get a new token:

```
gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

Although it would be nice if there was a way to do this in code in the event the token is revoked again.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly yesterday we faced a similar issue in Google OAuth2 connection from gerrit code review. So just wanted to share this as it might be related to you. Refer this [github issue](https://github.com/davido/gerrit-oauth-provider/issues/64) & its [commit made for gerrit-oauth-provider](https://github.com/davido/gerrit-oauth-provider/pull/65/files)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response.  I'm not sure it's related though.  Mine stopped working when a security tool (CloudLock) revoked the OAuth token from my Google account.  The client library is assuming the token is still valid, but it's not, and needs to get a new one.